# How to add multiple columns in a MySQL table with PHP form?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in my database with 2 columns.What I want to do is to let the admin (of the web application ) have the possibility from a simple php/html form to add multiple columns in the table already created.

Thanks.

Comment: There is something very wrong with your db schema if you need to change table structure on a regular basis.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the db schema, I want to give the admin the possibility to add 2,3,4,etc extra columns if he needs for administrating the site.

Answer (score 1):

when you access your web application as admin then try this query

```
ALTER TABLE Table Name
ADD (column1 col_definition,
column2 col_definition,
column3 col_definition,
....      ......
....      ......
columnN col_definition);
```

Answer (score 0):

so what give admin to fill the required info for the column and run query if admin enter valid info

```
alter table table_name add column <colname> <datatype> <otheroption>
```

Answer (score 0):

To add multiple table columns if they don not exist
`alter table_name add column IF NOT EXISTS (`
`<colname1> <datatype> DEFAULT VALUE,`
`<colname2> <datatype> DEFAULT VALUE,`
`<colname3> <datatype> DEFAULT VALUE,`
`<colname4> <datatype> DEFAULT VALUE)`